# Быстродействие загрузки данных из DB2 в Oracle

Tags: oracle, производительность, odbc, db2

Вопрос сложный и неоднозначный, но надеюсь на любые советы (а может кому и мой опыт поможет):

1. Есть сервер с Oracle 11.2.0.3 x32 на Windows Server 2008R2 x64 (4ядра/8 потоков, 8гб оперативы, один HDD без рейда).
2. В источниках ODBCx32 настроено подключение к DB2 через CLI DRIVER с именем db2
3. Целевой сервер DB2 находится на мейнфрейме, настроек которого я не знаю, версия 9fix15
4. Поднят дополнительный listener:

   ```
   SID_LIST_LISTENERdb2 =
     (SID_LIST =
       (SID_DESC=
            (SID_NAME=db2)
            (ORACLE_HOME=C:\app\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1)
            (PROGRAM=dg4odbc))
     )
   LISTENERdb2 =
    (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
       (DESCRIPTION =
         (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1523))
       )
     )
   ```

   В tnsnames.ora:

   ```
   db2 =
    (DESCRIPTION=
      (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1523))
      (CONNECT_DATA=(SID=db2))
      (HS=OK)
   )
   ```
5. Создан public dblink:

   ```
   CREATE PUBLIC DATABASE LINK db2 CONNECT TO
   "login" IDENTIFIED BY "pwd" using 'db2';`
   ```
6. Создана процедура:

   ```
   CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE P_LOAD_DATA IS 
   BEGIN 
   insert into data_table select * from data_table@db2 d where d.date_op between TRUNC(SYSDATE - 4/24, 'HH24') + 1/24/60 AND TRUNC(SYSDATE - 2/24, 'HH24'));
   END;/
   ```
7. Создан job на запуск процедуры раз в 2 часа (или 12 джобов на каждый запуск).

Целевая таблица размером примерно 13млн записей по 50 столбцов, моя таблица собирает архив из целевой и имеет размер примерно 150млн записей тех же 50 столбцов.

Перекачка ~600к записей (150-200мб) занимает в лучшем случае час, периодически переваливает за 4-5 часов. Плюс хорошо бы держать индексы на таблицу архива, чтобы из нее можно было потом что-то вытащить в приемлемый срок, но это опционально. **Корректный ли выбран способ наполнения архива или есть альтернативы лучше?** Проблема в том, что периодически джобы прерываются с причиной "Job slave process was terminated", а в логах

```
ORA-00603: ORACLE server session terminated by fatal error
ORA-28500: connection from ORACLE to a non-Oracle system returned this message:
[IBM][CLI Driver] CLI0106E  Connection is closed. SQLSTATE=08003 {08003,NativeErr = -99999}
ORA-02063: preceding 2 line
```

Это вероятно мейнфрейм закрывает подключение по таймауту.
Причина разрядности Оракла - ни один найденный вариант драйвера DB2 не работал на х64.

Comment: Не пробовали удаленно выгрузить данные из DB2 на диск, перекинуть файл (сама передача 200MB файла должна уложиться в минуту), а потом загрузить данные из него чем-то вроде [Oracle SQL Loader](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/SQL*Loader_FAQ)?

Comment: Не уверен как сработает с db2, но в оракле есть хинт DRIVING_SITE. При обычном запросе через dblink таблица полностью тянется на сторону оракла и уже в нем выполняются условия where. Данный же хинт отправляет запрос полностью выполнятся на стороне подключаемой базы, а в ответ возвращаются только результаты. Так же стоит учесть, что при первом варианте индексы не используются, а во втором будут если оптимизатор удаленной базы посчитает это нужным. Пример записи хинта 
    select /*+ DRIVING_SITE(d)*/ * from data_table@db2 d ...

Answer (score 4):

Ну, очевидно, стоит начать ковырять с анализа того, куда же уходит и час и 4 часа - т.е. включаем трассировку на сессию джоба и анализируем полученный трейс. Дальше, в порядке отработки версии что тормозит DB2 на мейнфрейме, я бы просто отселектил необходимый диапазон, но без записи в таблицу - т.е., как говорят в unix-мире, в /dev/null. Но при этом чтобы IBM отдал все записи и они прошли по сети и db-link'у - т.е. просто SELECT, но с COUNT'ом или группировкой + поиграть с хинтом +driving_site - чтоб точно все записи сначала пришли к нам в Оракл. Ну и потом уже - классические варианты записи большого объема в Oracle - NOLOGGING, +APPEND, варианты с временной таблицей (партицией) и DBMS_REDEFINITION / EXCHANGE PARTITION, удаление индексов до / пересоздание после, BULK INSERT и тд и тп.

Главное начать и выяснить, что оптимизировать или где затык. А дальше уже дело техники.

Если есть такая физическая/юридическая возможность + необходимость в предлагаемом - если Вы можете предоставить удаленный доступ - с удовольствием помогу решить (или хотя бы "осмотреть наружно" / применить озвученные выше рекомендации) текущую задачку "физически", бо интересный случай + имею предыдущий опыт в решении похожих ситуаций, когда перекачка данных в гетерогенных средах ведет себя не так, как ожидается.

Это предложение, кстати - подключиться и помочь удаленно - относится и ко всем остальным, кто рано или поздно попадет в этот тред/обсуждение (через поиск или еще как).